# Write the negation using logic symbols.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

1) $(\exists x \in R)[(x^2 = (x+1)^2 ∧ (x^3 \in Z))]$

ATTEMPT : $((∀ x \in R)[(x^2 \not= (x+1)^2 ∧ (x^3 \notin Z))])$

2)$(∀x \in R)(x>0) ⇒ (\exists n \in N)(n . x >1)$ Note: the (n.x)  is multiplication.

ATTEMPT: $(\exists x \in R)(x>0)∧(∀n \in N)(n . x <=1)$

Would be grateful if anyone could look my answers over.

Comment: Shouldn't the $\wedge$ in the first line change to something else in the second line?

Answer (score 5):

For the first, you need DeMorgan's to get $$(∀ x \in R)[(x^2 \not= (x+1)^2 \lor (x^3 \notin Z))]$$

For the second, we have an implication of the form $p \rightarrow q\equiv \lnot p \lor q$.

To negate it gives us, again, with DeMorgan's, $\lnot(\lnot p \lor q) \equiv p \land \lnot q$. So your quantifier in p should be $\forall$:

$$(\forall x \in R)\Big((x>0)∧(∀n \in N)(nx \leq 1)\Big)$$

Comment: +1 thanks, I knew that, just forgot to change it to or when I copy/pasted

Comment: You're welcome! Note also the first quantifier in the second problem. (Unless that's what you forgot to change.)

Comment: Great answer though eh, this is exactly a question, I am studying for from a past exam, this guy is probably getting ready for the same exam tomorrow :)

Comment: @amWhy I can't accept it, but I can upvote for sure :)...  So if I have two sets A,B.  ∀x(x∈A) → x∉B, would I get A^c ⊆ B, or would I negate ¬P and get A ⊆ B^c. Kind of confused when you say ¬p∨q

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV +1

Comment: Good answer. But I think that the right form of question has been archimedean principle: $\ (∀x \in R) \Big( (x>0) \rightarrow (\exists n \in N)(n\cdot x > 1)\Big )$ whose negation is: $(\exists x \in R)\Big ( (x>0)∧(∀n \in N)(n . x \leq 1)\Big )$ which @FA10m has tried to write.